# Running two AsyncTaskLoaders in Parallel

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, loader, android-support-library

I'm trying to create a search function that loads search results into a fragment's list. The problem is that the search does two requests to an API: one for type A and one for type B.

The way I implemented was to create a ViewPager with two fragments, FragmentA and FragmentB. Each calls the API endpoint with search query through a custom Loader extending AsyncTaskLoader, which does the API query and returns the results. This works as excepted; the fragments receive the search results and show them in a List.

The only problem I'm having with this construction is that while both fragments start their loaders with a seperate LOADER_IDs, only FragmentA actually calls `loadInBackground()` from the AsyncTaskLoader. *Only* when I swipe to FragmentB in the ViewPager doest it call `restartLoader()` (and in turn `loadInBackground()`), executing the API request for the search and returning the result.

The reason I want to run both loaders parallel is because when FragmentB has search results the ViewPager should show FragmentB.

SearchListFragment:

```
public class SearchListFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<SearchResults> {

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getLoaderManager().enableDebugLogging(BuildConfig.DEBUG);
        if (mSearchType == SearchType.ARTIST) {
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(R.id.search_artist_loader, null, this);
        } else {
            getLoaderManager().initLoader(R.id.search_track_loader, null, this);
        }
        BusProvider.getInstance().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<ApiResponse> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        int offset = 0;
        String query = null;
        if (args != null) {
            if (args.containsKey("offset")) {
                offset = args.getInt("offset");
            }
            if (args.containsKey(SearchManager.QUERY)) {
                query = args.getString(SearchManager.QUERY);
                mSearchQuery = query;
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateLoader for " + mSearchType.name());
        Log.d(TAG, "id: " + id);

        SearchLoader loader = new SearchLoader(getActivity(), mSearchType, offset, query);
        return loader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<SearchResults> loader, SearchResults data) {

        if (data != null) {
            if (data.mSampleList.isEmpty()) {
                mNoResults.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mAdapter.swapApiResponse(data);
                mListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            mLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            Exception exception = ((SearchLoader) loader).getError();
            if(exception != null) {
                Log.e(TAG, exception.toString());
                Log.e(TAG, exception.getMessage());
                Log.e(TAG, exception.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            mNoResults.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mLoading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<ApiResponse> loader) {

    }
}
```

CustomLoader:

```
public class SearchLoader extends AsyncTaskLoader<ApiResponse> {

    private static final String TAG = SearchLoader.class.getSimpleName();
    private SearchResults mApiResponse;
    private SearchType mSearchType;
    private int mOffset;
    private String mSearchQuery;
    private Exception error = null;

    public SearchLoader(Context context, SearchType type, int offset, String query) {
        super(context);
        mSearchType = type;
        mOffset = offset;
        mSearchQuery = query;
    }

    @Override
    public ApiResponse loadInBackground() {
        try {
            return tryLoadInBackground();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            error = e;
            return null;
        }
    }

    public ApiResponse tryLoadInBackground() throws Exception {
        if (mSearchQuery != null) {
            Map<String, String> parameters = Utils.parametersMap("q:" + mSearchQuery, "offset:" + String.valueOf(mOffset));
            if (mSearchType == SearchType.ARTIST) {
                return API.getRestAdapter().searchTypeA(parameters);
            } else {
                return API.getRestAdapter().searchTypeB(parameters);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartLoading for " + mSearchType.name());
        if (mApiResponse != null) {
            deliverResult(mApiResponse);
        }
        if (takeContentChanged() || mApiResponse == null) {
            forceLoad();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStopLoading() {
        cancelLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCanceled(ApiResponse data) {
        // Attempt to cancel the current asynchronous load.
        super.onCanceled(data);

        onReleaseResources(data);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReset() {
        // Ensure the loader has been stopped.
        onStopLoading();


        // At this point we can release the resources associated with 'apps' if needed
        if (mApiResponse != null) {
            onReleaseResources(mApiResponse);
            mApiResponse = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverResult(ApiResponse data) {
        if (isReset()) {
            // An async query came in while the loader is stopped. We don't need the result
            if (data != null) {
                onReleaseResources(data);
            }
            return;
        }
        SearchResults oldData = mApiResponse;
        mApiResponse = data;

        if (isStarted()) {
            // If the loader is currently started, we can immediately deliver a result
            super.deliverResult(mApiResponse);
        }

        // At this point we can release the resources associated with 'oldApps' if needed;
        // now that the new result is delivered we know that it is no longer in use
        if (oldData != null && oldData != mApiResponse) {
            onReleaseResources(oldData);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Helper function to take care of releasing resources associated with an actively loaded data set
     */
    private void onReleaseResources(ApiResponse data) {
        // For a simple list there is nothing to do
        // but for a Cursor we would close it here
    }

    public Exception getError() {
        return error;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you read this? It's probably too do with the executor.

http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/04/20/asynctask-threading-regression-confirmed.html

Comment: Im using the Supportlibrary AsyncTask which uses ModernAsyncTask with the default executor which is THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR. Which according to the java doc should execute parallel. But even if the execution was serial when the first loader is finished it should start the the second loaders task cause it should be in the threadpool if I'm not mistaken.